# Can I break concentration with Haste, before it ends, by casting another concentration spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

Example:

Turn 1: Cast *haste*. Do things.

Turn 2: Cast *invisibility* (end *haste*). Be invisible. No movement, no actions.

Turn 3: Be invisible. No movement, no actions. (Resolve *haste*)

---

The section on "[Concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration)" states:

> [...] You lose Concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires Concentration. You can’t concentrate on two Spells at once. [...]

The [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell states:

> Casting Time: 1 action [...]
>
> Duration: Up to 1 minute [...]
>
> When the spell ends, the target can’t move or take actions until after its next turn, as a wave of lethargy sweeps over it.

The [*invisibility*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invisibility) spell states:

> Casting Time: 1 action [...]
>
> Duration: Up to 1 hour [...]
>
> The spell ends for a target that attacks or casts a spell. [...]

Comment: Right now your question has been closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165540). If you feel this is not the case, feel free to [edit] your question to explain why. I'm personally not seeing what this scenario is trying to *do*; describing what you are trying to accomplish by ending concentration on the *haste* spell would make this more answerable and fit this site better. Speaking of which, hello and welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already done so and you can ask question or visit the [help] for further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [If you start casting a new concentration spell while concentrating on Haste, does the wave of lethargy interrupt the casting of the new spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165540/if-you-start-casting-a-new-concentration-spell-while-concentrating-on-haste-doe)